# How to show notification using ajax listener, after inserted a record in mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to know, how to show notification using the ajax listener after inserting a new record to the database.

The database name is `yanaDatabase` and the table name is `fuelManagement`.I am using `PHP` on the server-side. If someone inserts a new record, the system should show notification like **"You have new fuel record!"**.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `polling` or `websockets`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too vague, please add a code sample of what you have tried and where it goes wrong.

Comment: I did not try. because I have not an idea for how to solve this. I just want an idea.